# Needs of frequent disk access?

Tags: phoenix-framework

In the famous benchmarking of phoenix: http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/the-road-to-2-million-websocket-connections

I've noticed that I/O optimized machines were used, Rackspace says:

> Work-optimized server types
>
> I/O-optimized servers are assigned networking resources and use local
>   high-speed SSD drives for storage. I/O-optimized servers work best for
>   applications that require frequent or sustained disk access, like
>   databases.

Is there an explanation why would Phoenix needs a frequent disk access? are channels stored into memory or on disk? Is I/O optimization the first priority when we need to decide about server specs for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote that blog post! I can confirm that I/O optimized instances were not a priority, those just happen to be the types of machines that Rackspace kindly donated to us.

In our case, the important things for us were:

- Number of cores (this was important for the sharding optimization mentioned in the post. The new Elixir 1.4 registry will also parallelize the broadcasts (per [the docs on using it as a PubSub](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html#module-using-as-a-pubsub))
- Memory - as you can see in the post, running out of RAM was an issue when we were testing against the 15GB instances.